# Categorical variables splits in CatBoost

Tags: python, catboost

Is there any way to obtain splits for categorical variables for CatBoost in Python?

I used get_borders method, but it only gives splits for numerical data. I have problems with drawing a tree, but anyway I need the values in a form of list or data frame.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.